# Algorithm for finding last 5 digits of Fibonacci number

Tags: java, algorithm, iteration, fibonacci

I'm trying to implement an iterative algorithm for computing the last 5 digits of the Nth Fibonacci number. I have no issue finding the nth Fibonacci number itself and displaying only the last 5 digits, however, my assignment also asks to find the maximum n for which my program runs under 1 minute. The problem is, the N gets very huge, and therefore Fibonacci numbers are huge as well. Should I just use BigInteger to store values and in the end use % operator to display 5 last digits? Is there a way to use the fact that I only need last 5 digits to speed up the process? I feel like I'm missing the point of the assignment.

Assignment says this: 
Using Java, implement the iterative algorithm for computing the last 5 digits of the nth Fibonacci number. Perform an experiment to find the largest value of n for which your program runs under 1 minute on your computer.

My code for finding last 5 digits of Nth Fibonacci number:

```
public static int Fibonacci(int n){
    int a, b = 0, c = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a + b;
    }
    return c % 100000;
}
```

I would also love to know if there are better iterative solutions.

Comment: You can use `int` since the intermediate results only need to be computed modulo 100,000. But you need to do the remainder operation in the loop.

Comment: Thank you! But how does the math work here? I was thinking about this solution but for some reason haven't tried it since I really didn't believe it would work.

Comment: The bottom 5 digits of a sum depend only on the bottom 5 digits of each summand, because the carry only goes from right to left (left digits get no chance to influence digits to the right of themselves).

Comment: If execution time is of essence, one should never use `BigInteger` or`BigDecimal` if not absolutely necessary since those classes are terrible slow compared to the primitives and even the wrappers.

Comment: The math: when adding two numbers, the last 5 digits of the sum can only be affected by the last 5 digits of the numbers. So the code only needs to keep the last 5 digits of `c`. Which means that you don't need the modulo operator. The largest number you should have in `a` and `b` is 99999. When you compute `c`, it will be between 00000 and 199998. Which means that after computing `c`, you can trim it to 5 digits with `c = (c >= 100000) ? (c - 100000) : c;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already noticed, finding the last 5 digits is equivalent to calculating the result modulo 100000. To solve the overflow issue, you can apply the `% 100000` operation to the intermediate results so no BigInteger is required. It would be: `c = (a + b) % 100000`.

In theory, you can improve the time complexity of the solution from O(N) to O(log(N)). The algorithm is based on fast matrix exponentiation. However, your assignment requires the iterative approach so I mention it just for completeness.

Answer (score 6):

Ardavel's answer has a good, clear explanation of why taking the remainder in the loop gives the correct result, so that you don't need to use BigInteger. So for the purpose of your assignment, this question is answered; but the problem is too interesting to leave it there. And you said:

> I would also love to know if there are better iterative solutions.

So, here goes:

#### Matrix multiplication

Ardavel mentions that you can compute the same result in O(log n) time by computing a [matrix power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) with an efficient matrix power algorithm. Essentially, the n-th Fibonacci number can be written in a closed form as:

```
( ... ) = ( 1 1 )n ( 1 )
( F_n )   ( 1 0 )  ( 0 )
```

And this matrix to the power of `n` can be computed in O(log n) time e.g. using the [square and multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm, which *can* be implemented iteratively - and the iterative version is more efficient than the recursive version.

#### "O(1) time" solution

In fact, you can do even better using the following observation: let's call the matrix equation above `A^n v` where `v` is the initial vector. There are only finitely many 2D integer vectors modulo 100,000, and only finitely many 2x2 integer matrices. So there is some finite number `t` such that `A^t v = v`.

This means that `A^n = A^(n % t)`, and it follows that **however large `n` is**, you only need to do at most a **fixed, constant** amount of matrix multiplication. It turns out that the value of `t` is 150,000, so we can improve on any algorithm by writing `n %= 150000;` at the start.

However, this solution isn't quite O(1) time because the remainder modulo `t` cannot be found in constant time for arbitrarily large `n`. Supposing we allow the input to be arbitrarily large (the rest of the computation can still be done using `int`s), then the time it takes to even read the input in a binary format is O(log n). But this is a much better O(log n) than having to do O(log n) matrix multiplications.

#### Chinese remainder theorem

We can go a step further. If we apply the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) then it's sufficient to find the answer modulo 2<sup>5</sup> and the answer modulo 5<sup>5</sup>, since these uniquely determine the answer modulo 10<sup>5</sup>. It turns out the cycle length `t` is much shorter in both cases: for the modulus 2<sup>5</sup>, `t` is just 48, and for 5<sup>5</sup> it's 12,500.

This is small enough that if performance is of great importance, we can feasibly just precompute the results for the smaller moduli in arrays of length 48 and 12,500 respectively. These numbers are small enough to fit in 2-byte `short`s, so the arrays take up about 25KB or so of memory, compared to about 600KB needed to store 150,000 `int`s if you were to precompute an array for `t` = 150,000.

The algorithm then is *"take n modulo 48 and 12,500, look up in the two arrays, and apply the Chinese remainder theorem"*, which is not really iterative, but at least you could argue that the arrays were precomputed using an iterative algorithm.

Comment: That's nice and all, but you're making the task much harder. They're supposed to *"find the largest value of n for which your program runs under 1 minute on your computer"*. Now how do you do that if you can solve pretty much every n instantly?!? :-D

Comment: If the remainder operations are calculated efficiently, then I estimate that the largest number it works for is about `2^(max heap size in bits - heap space already used)`, unless your heap is so large that it can't be iterated over in one minute.

Comment: Sounds right, but also complicated to find out how large you can make your free heap space. I think the smart move would be to sleep for two minutes inside their loop, then the answer would simply be n=1.

Comment: Great answer. I just wonder how you got to `t = 150000`. Did you brute-force it? Or is there some math behind this?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn It should be possible to derive t = 150,000 by hand, but I figured it would be easier to brute-force it, so I did that (it took a few lines of Python and well under a second to run). There is a bit of maths missing from my answer, though; the argument from finiteness only works because the matrix `A` is invertible.